# In F#, How do I hydrate a type based on a parsed payload?

Tags: f#

I'm from an imperative programming background and am having problems understanding how to achieve (what should be) a relatively simple programming task...

Imagine I have an F# type:

```
type MyType(description: string, active:bool) =
    member this.Description = description
    member this.Active = active
```

I want to create and hydrate an instance of this type based on a delimited payload:

```
DE=MyDescription;AC=0
```

wherein AC is 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`.

I have written a couple of functions to perform the parsing:

```
let RecordParser (record:string) = 
    record.Split([|';'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

let AttributeParser (kvp:string) =
    kvp.Split [|'='|]
```

What would the implementation of a function that parses the delimited payload to return a new instance of MyType that is hydrated with the parsed `Description` and `Active` values look like?

I've tried a route with `Array.iter` but I can't seem to get it to, when `match`ing on the keys, to compile. I've got as far as:

```
let Hydrater payload
    let kvps = RecordParser payload
    kvps |> Array.iter(fun (x) -> 
    // How to match on the keys of "DE" and "AC" to extract the value and construct MyType
    ()
    )
```

Comment: in this case you would do the same as in C# (as it's only known at runtime): check if you have enought records, check for each record if you have enough parts and then use array-indexing (`.[i]`) and your usual boolean and comparision functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume for a minute that `MyType` was defined as a [record type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx):

```
type MyType = {
    Description : string
    Active : bool
}
```

What you are describing can be thought of as an accumulation of the values to overwrite on top of a default value:

```
let hydrate payload = 
    let kvps = RecordParser payload
    let startingValue = { Description = ""; Active = false }
    kvps 
    |> Seq.fold 
        (fun state kvp -> 
            match kvp with
            | [| 'Description'; '='; description |] -> { state with Description = description }
            | [| 'AC'; '='; '0' |] -> { state with Active = false }
            | [| 'AC'; '='; '1' |] -> { state with Active = true }
            | _ -> failwith "Not implemented") startingValue
```

Here `startingValue` is the "default" value. [`Seq.fold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353471.aspx) takes the `startingValue` and uses it as the initial value of `state`. After each evaluation of the function, the return value is then passed to the next call to the function as `state`. In general, you can use `Seq.fold` to replace certain kinds of `foreach` loops in C#.

This F#:

```
Seq.fold (fun state curr -> doSomething state curr) startingValue items
```

Is roughly equivelant to this C#:

```
var state = startingValue;
foreach(var curr in items) 
{
    state = doSomething(state, curr);
}
```

Comment: Forgive me for being a bit slow, but could you please explain how Seq.fold is taking startingValue? Is it somehow passed implicitly?

Comment: @thehowler Does my latest edit wrt Seq.fold make sense?

Comment: yes it does. I missed the implicit type of the "state" value.